# PHP Page Navigation Optimizing - Setting "active" on nav items

Tags: php, html

I have my nav.php setup with code like this. This is to determine the page and then set both the navigation header and the item as active.

```
if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == ''.$path.'/links.php') {
    $opslinks = "active";
    $nav1_active = "active";
} elseif($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == ''.$hpath.'/tunnel_status.php') {
    $tunnelstatus = "active";
    $nav2_active = "active";
    $refresh = "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"240\"/>";
} elseif($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == ''.$hpath.'/qcall_status.php') {
    $qcallstatus = "active";
    $nav2_active = "active";
} elseif ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == ''.$path.'/checklist.php') {
    $opsdash = "active";
    $nav1_active = "active";
} elseif ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == ''.$path.'/index.php') {
    $opsindex = "active";
    $nav1_active = "active";    
} elseif ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == ''.$path.'/tasks_closed.php') {
    $optaskclosed = "active";
    $nav1_active = "active";
}
```

I then have the following html code.

```
                        <div class="menu-submenu">
                            <div class="menu-item <?=$opsindex ?? '';?>">
                                <a href="<?=$path ?? '';?>/index.php" class="menu-link "><div class="menu-text">Home</div></a>
                            </div>                        
                            <div class="menu-item <?=$opsdash ?? '';?>">
                                <a href="<?=$path ?? '';?>/checklist.php" class="menu-link "><div class="menu-text">Checklist</div></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="menu-item <?=$opsoutages ?? '';?>">
                                <a href="<?=$path ?? '';?>/outages.php" class="menu-link"><div class="menu-text">Outage Management</div></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="menu-item <?=$opsissues ?? '';?>">
                                <a href="<?=$path ?? '';?>/tasks.php" class="menu-link"><div class="menu-text">Task List / Issues</div></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="menu-item <?=$optaskclosed ?? '';?>">
                                <a href="<?=$path ?? '';?>/tasks_closed.php" class="menu-link"><div class="menu-text">Task List (Closed)</div></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="menu-item <?=$opslinks ?? '';?>">
                                <a href="<?=$path ?? '';?>/links.php" class="menu-link"><div class="menu-text">Common Links</div></a>
                            </div>                            
                        </div>
```

How can I optimize this as I feel this is horribly done and outdated. I've been working on cleaning up all my older code and this is one area I'm not sure about. I know I could technically add the code into the html block itself, but it's not really any better that way.

I also realize the php code block only partially matches what I posted. I have dozens of links, so to condense the info and present enough, I truncated it down.

I'm also working on revamping my PATH variables to be constants and defined in a single file, its sort of a mess at the moment. :)

Comment: You could start by putting all the relevant information - link text & href - into a multidimensional array, and then you loop over that to create the HTML for each navigation item dynamically. Then the necessary conditional logic to decide whether the current item is the active one or not, also needs to be written in one single place.

Comment: What @CBroe said. I think that's the easiest way to do it. Keep them in an array, or in a database table if you want, and when you are displaying them, check if the current link equals one of them, and if that's the case, add an extra class or extra style to that menu item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the approach outlined by @CBroe comment above

```
// set up an array on the php side with a mapping to then loop over to create the nav elements
// the skeleton code below should work with some modifications

$nav_options = [ 
    ['page_link' => 'links.php', 'link_text' => 'Common Links' ], 
    [],
    ...
]

$arr = [];
foreach( $nav_options as $key => $nav_opt ) {
    $url = $path . '/' . $nav_opt["page_link"];
    if( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == $url ){
        // active
        $arr[$key]['css_class'] = 'active';
        $arr[$key]['link_href'] = $url;
        $arr[$key]['link_text'] = $nav_opt['link_text'];
    } else {
        // not active 
        $arr[$key]['css_class'] = '';
        $arr[$key]['link_href'] = $url;
        $arr[$key]['link_text'] = $nav_opt['link_text'];
    }
}

// Then loop over $arr on the html side to produce the nav div elements
```

Comment: Quick question, should I need to use array_push? The $arr only seems to have the last item in nav_options. Using print_r to show the value of it.

Comment: @Kelso good spot, I edited my code there and I think it should be good now, please take a look. You could probably do it with array_push() too but I just prefer this way with keys.

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much, this makes things so much cleaner.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69122268/php-page-navigation-using-arrays-and-foreach-trouble-with-category-level-acti  - I added a new question based on what Ive changed for categories, any suggestions? :)

Comment: @Kelso sorry I am only seeing this now. I had a look at your other post there and your solution makes sense to me - it should work.